# How to get the room IDs of rooms in a namespace in Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a namespace named `privateNamespace` and I have created rooms under that namespace. I want to get all the room IDs under that namespace.

I have tried:

```js
const privateNamespace = io.of("/private");
const rooms = privateNamespace.adapter.rooms;

socket.join("room1");
socket.join("room2");

for (const roomID of rooms.keys()) {
  console.log("roomID", roomID);
}
```

Output:

```
roomID DAXUtoNgOtjlGqfyAAAB
roomID room1
roomID room2
```

The above output gives the socket id for each connection made. I don't want the socket IDs. I just want the room IDs.

Solution that worked out for me:

```js
const privateNamespace = io.of("/private");
const rooms = privateNamespace.adapter.rooms;

socket.join("room1");
socket.join("room2");

const roomIDs = new Set();

// Iterate over the rooms and extract room IDs
for (const [roomID, room] of rooms.entries()) {
  if (room.size > 0 && !room.has(roomID)) {
    // Check if there are clients in the room and it's not a socket ID
    roomIDs.add(roomID);
  }
}

for (const roomID of roomIDs) {
  console.log("roomID", roomID);
}
```

Output:

```
roomID room1
roomID room2
```

Is there a convenient way in Socket.io 4.x to achieve this? Thanks.